# what is no-oo mvc in php?

Tags: php, oop, procedural

what is no-oo mvc in php?

If it is possible, give an example.
If not, why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Object oriented vs. MVC (CodeIgniter)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72919/php-object-oriented-vs-mvc-codeigniter)

Comment: You should make your point clear just creating an account and asking some silly question and Googleing for question in not we appreciate here.Make it clear what you want us to answer

Comment: why is the linked question a duplicate?

Comment: The accepted answer answers the question that OO and MVC aren't mutually exclusive and gives examples of a framework.  Pretty much exactly what wiiman is asking.

Comment: @Michael The OP's specifically asking for non-OO MVC. The question is tagged procedural. That's not answered in the purported duplicate. It's aimed at OO and CI.

Comment: Quite right :/  Well - apologies wiiman, as you were.

Comment: If anything, it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023818/any-procedural-non-oo-php-framework, but I'd rather say it's just related.

Answer (score 4):

MVC's main point is to [split user interface interaction into three distinct roles.](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/modelViewController.html) The most important separation is between model (M) and presentation layer (V and C). MVC does not say which paradigm to use. And since Prodecural coding does not mean unorganized coding, it's very much possible to use this paradigm for this pattern.